# MySQL: Table alias doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I want to rewrite this query so it would be working with table and column alias, but I can't get it working. After some research I found that we cannot use table alias in WHERE clause, I tried to change WHERE to HAVING, but still not working ...

Does anyone have a better idea?

This is the query:

```
SELECT   pos.pat_id+1000 as Barcode
        ,pat_sex as Sex 
        ,pat_dob as DoB
        ,Test 
        ,Required_diagnosis
        ,Sample_date
        ,Location 
        ,DQ_list

FROM    (SELECT  icv_pat_id as pat_id
            ,icv_test_name as Test
            ,'Trichomonas' as Required_diagnosis
            ,lrr_request_date as Sample_date
            ,d.Location
            ,d.DQ_List          
        FROM investigation_component_values
        INNER JOIN lab_result_records l on l.lrr_rrc_id = icv_rrc_id
        LEFT JOIN lookups.dq_lists d ON d.lrr_ordering_location_name = l.lrr_ordering_location_name
        WHERE lrr_request_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31'
        AND icv_pat_id NOT IN (SELECT pat_id FROM cnwlreports.test_patients)
        AND icv_ist_id = 83882
        AND icv_non_quantifiable_result = 'Trichomonas vaginalis ISOLATED') as pos
LEFT JOIN trungnguyen.patients pat on  pos.pat_id = pat.pat_id

WHERE pos.pat_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.pat_id
                        FROM pos p
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT    rrc_pat_id as pat_id
                                            ,rrc_clinic_date as diag_date                                               
                                    FROM referral_records 
                                    WHERE rrc_status = 'approved'
                                    AND rrc_answered_id = 17380
                                    AND rrc_clinic_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-08-01',INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
                                    AND DATE_ADD('2015-08-31',INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
                                    AND rrc_pat_id IN (SELECT pat_id FROM pos)
                                    GROUP BY    rrc_pat_id 
                                                ,rrc_clinic_Date) d ON p.pat_id = d.pat_id
                        WHERE ABS(datediff(sample_date,diag_date)) < 7
                        )
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing table aliases and column aliases. A column alias is defined in a `SELECT` and cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause for that `SELECT`.

A *table* alias is defined in the `FROM` clause. It can -- and should -- be  used whenever columns from that table are used. Such a column name, with a table alias, is called a *qualified column*.

For example, from your subquery:

```
SELECT  icv.icv_pat_id as pat_id,
        icv.icv_test_name as Test,
        'Trichomonas' as Required_diagnosis,
        lrr.lrr_request_date as Sample_date
        . . .
FROM investigation_component_values icv INNER JOIN
     lab_result_records lrr
     on lrr.lrr_rrc_id = icv.icv_rrc_id

WHERE lrr.lrr_request_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' . . .
```

`pat_id`, `test`, `Required_diagnosis` and `Sample_date` are all *column alias*. `icv` and `lrr` are *table* aliases. In the `WHERE` clause, you can have:

```
WHERE lrr.lrr_request_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' . . .
```

But you cannot have:

```
WHERE Sample_Date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the real column name, so in the 'WHERE pos.pat_id' for example, You should use: 'WHERE pos.icv_pat_id'.

Answer (score 0):

generally you can use alias for table in where clause;
Normally , I do:

```
Select * from Table T, Table2 T2 WHERE T.key = T2.key;
```

For example, try to explicit inner join with this syntax.